# Checking 3 values if are the same with If Statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am building a Tic Tac Toe game and I am wondering if this syntax could be valid. It seems the program sometimes is running correctly and sometimes not so i would like your opinion.

```
If ( (spacesArray[0] &&
      spacesArray[1] &&
      spacesArray[2] == (userDraw || compDraw))){
  }
```

So basically i am checcking positions 0,1,2 in an Array if they have the same value ("x" OR "o"). Is this syntax correct?

**Edit

For anyone that want to see the full project here it is.
https://codepen.io/Ispaxan/pen/ZaRjZW?editors=0001

Comment: no, just write it 3 times, programming is easy no need to overcomplicate

Comment: I need And because all the values need to be the same for this game. I was thinking i could simplify it with this way to be honest.

Comment: See my updated answer below for the best way to do this which is simpler and more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have a separate check for if `userDraw` or `compDraw` so you can tell who wins.  Also, use `===` instead of `==` for javascript quirky equality reasons.

```
// destructure array
const [a, b, c] = spacesArray;

// check if a is not null or undefined
// check if a and b are equal
// check if a and c are equal
if (a && a === b && a === c) {
  // all 3 are the same value      

  // check if userDraw wins
  if (a === userDraw) {
    console.log(`${userDraw} wins`;
  }

  // check if compDraw wins
  if (a === compDraw) {
    console.log(`${compDraw} wins`;
  } 
}
```

** Elaborating on why the `||` won't work in this case. **

Setup:

```
const userDraw = 'x';
const compDraw = 'y';
const spacesArray = ['y', 'y', 'y'];

// (userDraw || compDraw) will be 'x'
```

Case:

```
if (spacesArray[0] &&
  spacesArray[1] &&
  spacesArray[2] == (userDraw || compDraw)
```

Here's where it fails:

```
if ('y' && // -> true
  'y' && // -> true
  'y' === 'x') // -> false
```

Case:

```
if (spacesArray[0] === spacesArray[1] &&
  spacesArray[0] === spacesArray[2] &&
  spacesArray[0] === (userDraw || compDraw))
```

Here's where it fails:

```
spacesArray[0] === spacesArray[1] // 'y' === 'y' -> true
spacesArray[0] === spacesArray[2] // 'y' === 'y' -> true
spacesArray[0] === (userDraw || compDraw) // 'y' === 'x' -> false
```

Comment: I will try to implement this now

Comment: You can use that too.  Using `(a && a === b && a === c)` checks that `a` actually has a value in it.  That way you can't get true with `null === null`

Comment: I tried being a little more explicit in my answer on why the original question and the most up voted question would fail the if checks.  If this works for you, would you mind marking this answer as correct.  Thanks and I'm glad it helped!

Comment: This worked although it took me a bit. Just a note. The syntax does work only with (a && a === b...). Although i do not fully understand why. Without it was evaluating a win within a single click into the game.

Comment: If you don't do `(a && a === b...`, you can get false positives because it could essentially be `null === null && null === null` which would evaluate as true which would `win` in your game.

Answer (score 4):

You mean the same value. So the first thing you need to check is 3 item was equally.

When 3 values was equally, you just need to check one of them equal `userDraw` or `compDraw` and done.

By this way. You can make your `if` statement run faster because when first or second condition was fail, javascript engine will not do a check for remain conditions.

```
if (spacesArray[0] === spacesArray[1] &&
    spacesArray[0] === spacesArray[2] &&
    (spacesArray[0] === userDraw || spacesArray[0] === compDraw) )
```

Edited: I was checking the Codepen and noticed that. This is gonna a bug if you check `spacesArray[0] === (userDraw || compDraw)`. because `(userDraw || compDraw)` will always return userDraw.

Comment: This is a much cleaner answer. I would just suggest that there be an if statement inside to see who won. `if(spacesArray[0] == userDraw){} else{}`

Comment: I have added a variable that checks that. I still can't get a win from the computer although it goes through the evaluation function. I am revising this now.

Comment: @BStill yeah you're correct. But I think that only have problem with this condition so I don't want to get out of the context. btw thanks for your idea :)

Comment: Problem still persists. compDraw is not calculated. I think i need to run tests simpler problems for this syntax

Comment: Can you try == instead of === . could it be problem with type checking ?

Comment: i just did with ==. It still evaluates my answers and calculates a win but not for the computer's answers. I think (userDraw || compDraw) is where the problem is

Comment: The problem is the `(userDraw || compDraw)` comparison.  It doesn't apply in this case.  Check out my answer above.  Using the `||` syntax will give you false positives.  If `userDraw` has a value, it will NEVER be == `compDraw`

Comment: @VtoCorleone yeah. you're right. I just check the codepen and notice that. CompDraw was never checked. Because UserDraw always have a value.

Answer (score 1):

I think when you put just `spacesArray[0]` by itself then it checks if it is true or false.

you might want to try:

`if ( (spacesArray[0] == (userDraw || compDraw) &&
      spacesArray[1] == (userDraw || compDraw) &&
      spacesArray[2] == (userDraw || compDraw))){
  }`

Comment: i will try this

Comment: The only problem with this is that your checking if it is drawn rather than who drew it. So this probably wont work when displaying a winner. 

`if (spacesArray[0] == userDraw &&
      spacesArray[1] == userDraw &&
      spacesArray[2] == userDraw { // user wins}
 else if (spacesArray[0] == compDraw &&
      spacesArray[1] == compDraw &&
      spacesArray[2] == compDraw) { // comp wins}`

Comment: This is not gonna work. You missing to check if 3 values was equally or not. :)

Comment: This evaluates a win for userDraw but it misses the compDraw win

Comment: @Kostis Did the answer in my comment work? If not than chiquyet has the better answer.

Answer (score 0):

First verify the equality between answers, and finally if its O or X

```
if ( spacesArray[0] == spacesArray[1] &&
    spacesArray[0] == spacesArray[2] &&
    spacesArray[0] == (userDraw || compDraw))
```

Answer (score -1):

First, it's `if`, not `If` and second, no, that's not the right syntax. Each test must be complete and independent of the others, as in:

```
if (spacesArray[0] == (userDraw || compDraw) &&
    spacesArray[1] == (userDraw || compDraw) &&
    spacesArray[2] == (userDraw || compDraw)){
}
```

But, in your case, none of that is necessary because you are performing the wrong test in the first place. You should be checking to see if all 3 elements in the `spacesArray` are the same value, that would mean that they are all "X's" or all "O's" and that can be most efficiently done with the **[`Array.prototype.every()`](http://function%20isBelowThreshold(currentValue)%20%7B%20%20%20return%20currentValue%20%3C%2040;%20%7D%20%20var%20array1%20=%20[1,%2030,%2039,%2029,%2010,%2013];%20%20console.log(array1.every(isBelowThreshold));%20//%20expected%20output:%20true)** method.

```js
function allX(currentValue) {
  return currentValue === "X";
}

function allO(currentValue) {
  return currentValue === "O";
}

var spacesArray1 = ["X", "O", "O"];
var spacesArray2 = ["X", "X", "O"];
var spacesArray3 = ["X", "X", "X"];
var spacesArray4 = ["O", "O", "O"];

console.log(spacesArray1.every(allX), spacesArray1.every(allO));
console.log(spacesArray2.every(allX), spacesArray2.every(allO));
console.log(spacesArray3.every(allX), spacesArray3.every(allO));
console.log(spacesArray4.every(allX), spacesArray4.every(allO));

// So, to test for tic-tac-toe:
function test(player){
  if(spacesArray3.every(allX) || spacesArray3.every(allO)){
    console.log(player + " wins!");
  } else {
    console.log("Not yet!");
  }
}

test("Scott");
```

Comment: This will be verified for XOX, XXX, OXO... and the author wants to be verified only for XXX OR OOO

Comment: you play this game when one player or the computer matches (x-x-x) or (o-o-o) horizontally,vertically or diagonal. So i need the and condition

Comment: @Kostis Answer updated. But, it is correct, so please up vote it and mark it as "the" answer.

Comment: I think op wants something like `array[0]===array[1]&&array[1]===array[2]&&(array[0]===userDraw||array[0]==compDraw)`

Comment: @ScottMarcus as previously mentionned its not correct, XOX will be true and the author want 3 same values

Comment: @iguypouf I wasn't really addressing the X's and O's logic, but was addressing the `if` syntax. However, I've updated the answer to show the best way, which is not to use an `if` statement at all and use the `Array.every()` method, which this is a textbook use case for.